# Best way to perform statistical analysis on data that has small scattering on y-axis and much more significant on x-axis

Tags: regression, survival

I am just an engineering student, so please correct me if my thinking is incorrect.

I have carried out tests (fatigue) where the two variables are the load (y-axis) and the lifetime duration (x-axis).

The issue I'm having is that, first, I have loading values (y-axis) that are not evenly distributed. Example: loading is grouped around levels 10, 20, 30, and 40 Newtons, but at each level there is scattering of around +/- 3 N at most. So in a sense, there is a gap between each level.

As for the lifetime (x-axis), the scale here is actually logarithmic. And the scattering here is much more significant. Example: at 10 N, the min lifetime could be around 10,000 cycles and max lifetime more than 2 million cycles. At 40 N, from 300 cycles to 4,000.

(There are two additional constraints: I can only test at most 10 samples per loading level) and at 10 N for example I have several unbroken specimens (i.e. 4 out of 10).

I plotted the values below.
[image]

And so, I am stuck on how to best perform statistical analysis on this set of data.

Ignoring the unbroken specimens, from literature, what's usually done is simple power law regression. But due to the scattering, I find that it is insufficient, and especially since unbroken specimens are ignored.

Another common method is fitting a Weibull distribution. With median rank tables, it seems to work on small number of specimens and takes into account the unbroken specimens. But the problem is that this method is applied only when there is scattering on 1 axis - lifetime.

So I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I've looked at the fatigue related available literature, but I cannot find anything relevant.

What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Are you sure you have $x$ and $y$ the right way round?

Comment: I am not an engineer, but my sense is that lifetime depends on loading. I see nothing very unusual here: you have a lot of scatter. To firm up your question, explain what you mean by "I find that it is insufficient".

Comment: It would probably help to make a plot.

Comment: This sounds like a standard survival analysis problem.  It's not multivariate analysis--that's where you have *responses* that are vectors rather than numbers--and it's not about distributions, so I removed those tags. There's nothing either special or unusual about your load data. The big issue is the censoring of the lifetimes (where you have only a lower bound), which is what survival analysis methods handle.

Comment: @mdewey yes, loading is changed to measure the lifetime

Comment: @whuber thank you for your edits, this is acutally what i was missing, the proper term that is used to describe this sort of analysis.

I will look further in this direction, but from my first look, I'm still not sure how I can deal with the scatter in the loading. I imagine i could apply survival method analysis if my loading values were consistent. Maybe I'm missing something, but I feel lost to be honest.

Comment: @NickCox insufficient because with just power law regression, i cannot take into account the samples that did not break, i.e. i have no lifetime points for it. Of course I could discard them, but then I think that I skew my analysis?

Comment: Scatter in loading is no problem with survival analysis. It's utterly standard and indeed a feature.

Comment: @NickCox i've found kaplan meier method, but for it i encounter the same problem, i can only look at only 1 variable at the time. do i need to use a cox model on top of that? 
could you perhaps point me to some articles or books? because i'm having trouble finding how to incorporate scatter in y-axis. i don't know, maybe i'm using wrong search terms....thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could explain just what you're trying to use these data to find out. Why does it matter what axes you've plotted load & lifetime on? A very natural question would be how lifetime depends on load, & regression methods that account for the censored lifetime observations can answer that. If there are reasons to consider a power-law or Weibull distribution for lifetime conditional on load, you can get maximum-likelihood parameter estimates even with censoring (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Fitting_parameters_to_data), ....

Comment: ...  else the semi-parametric Cox proportional hazards model you suggest sounds like at least a good starting point.